# Cannot access url on my dockerized web app endpoint

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have started my .net core 3.1 web app under docker container and I'm having info from docker desktop client

```
Now listening on: http://[::]:80    
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]    
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.    
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]    
Hosting environment: Development    
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]    
Content root path: /app
```

My controller looks like this

```
 [Route("hello/[controller]")]
 public class WorldController : ControllerBase
 {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
       return Ok();
    }
 }
```

since my container is running on port 80 I'm trying to access controller action using

```
http://localhost/hello/world
```

but I'm getting **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

Am I missing something? Any suggestions?

Update:

```
Dockerfile
...

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:57362
EXPOSE 57362
```

Even though I'm explicitly exposing 57362 docker still gives the message   `Now listening on: http://[::]:80`

Comment: How are you running the container? The port is 80 inside the container, but that could be mapped to another port in you local machine. The other thing to note is that the container might running as a different host (on your machine) instead of `localhost`.

Comment: are you suggesting that I should use other non used port (not 80)?

Comment: When you start a container, docker maps the port 80 inside the container to some other port number outside the container. We need to find out what that port is. I am almost sure it's not port 80 outside the container.

Comment: Can you please give more detail info, how can I investigate this port usage?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/ seems like a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the port ASPNETCORE will listen with the following directive in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
```

If you want to change the default HTTP port to be 57362 you should do:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:57362
```

After building the docker image, the application will run under port 57362 **inside the container**. To forward any port of your computer to the container port you need to run the container with the **-p** parameter as follows:

```
docker run -tid -p <host_port>:<container_port> my_image:<my_tag>
```

In your case it should be the following:

```
docker run -tid -p 80:57362 my_image:<my_tag>
```

If you're running this script on Windows on Docker for Desktop, it will only allow the binding of port 80 from an elevated prompt. If not running on an elevated prompt you can change it to port 8080 or any other.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map port 80 to 57362. This would look something like this inside a docker-compose.yml file if you have a docker-compose file thats to say and using the docker-compose up -build command

ports:

- 80:57362